# Combinatorics involved in Steiner triple systems

Tags: combinatorics

Steiner triple systems

Let $S$ be a Steiner triple system of order $15$: that is, $S$
is a set of “triples” or $3$-element subsets of ${1,...,15}$ such that any two distinct
elements of this set are contained in a unique triple. Then there are $35$ such triples, and two
distinct triples have at most one point in common.

This is an excerpt from an article I was reading. I am struck with the counting of such triplets. Any hint to figure out this no. $35$ will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Every number is in exactly 7 triplets, because it is once in a triplet with every other number. There are 14 other numbers and 2 per triplet.
- There are 15 numbers
- There are 3 numbers in every triplet.

Combining this facts gives $7*\frac{15}{3} = 35$ triplets.